# Why does .NET not clear errors internally?

Tags: c#, winapi, createfile, writefile, win32exception

I am running the following scenerio:

```
SafeFileHandle handle = Win32API.CreateFile((deviceName + "\\" + pipeName),
                           DesiredAccess.GENERIC_WRITE | DesiredAccess.GENERIC_READ,
                           ShareMode.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | ShareMode.FILE_SHARE_READ,
                           IntPtr.Zero,
                           CreationDisposition.OPEN_EXISTING,
                           FlagsAndAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FlagsAndAttributes.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                           IntPtr.Zero); // Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns 0 (success)

bool pass = Win32API.WriteFile(writeHandle, message.ToArray(), (uint)message.Count, ref bytes_written, ref over_lapped);
```

pass is false but to be expected since im running overlapped.
The problem is Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() doesnt return ERROR_IO_PENDING
it returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS. Which is weird to me because the error didnt show that when I created the file, but when I write it shows up.  Now I am trying to figure out how to close the handle that I dont seem to have access to or atleast get an explanation as to why this is happening.

EDIT: Ok, I have norrowed the problem down and I know what is causing the problem.

```
  private void ErrorOccurred(string detailedError)
  {
     lock (mLogLock)
     {
        try
        {
           System.IO.File.AppendAllText("Device" + mDeviceHandle + "Log.txt",
           DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": " + detailedError + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
     }
  }
```

Apparently, internally the AppendAllText call is creating an error.  Should I reset the error after this log call? I guess this would have been helpful to know that the framework doesnt reset low level calls in the internal workings of its functions. Ahh, you learn something new every day.

I guess the new question I have is, should I reset the low level error after this call, or is there some other way to log output (not using 3rd party tools like log4Net or getting fancy with the Debug.Trace output)?  Bascially someway to open a file for appending that doesnt affect the Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); output.

Comment: I dont really understand your problem: Is the code run simultanously by multiple threads? Is the File opened by a different application? Or does the file possible NOT exist?

Comment: The code is run on a thread by itself.  The File handle is opened on the main thread and passed into the running thread (and is checked to make sure its valid before calling WriteFile.  The CreateFile call works fine (returns a handle and its not InValid).  But the call to WriteFile fails with error ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined using `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` for debugging is not the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() should be the very first thing you do after the Win32API.WriteFile() call.  Don't do anything else, e.g. any logging etc, between the WriteFile() and GetLastWin32Error() calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use SetLastError = True in the DllImport declaration.

Comment: I have the following over all extern operations: [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]